# In which type of variable store time in millis? Choosing a correct data type

Tags: java, types, calendar, long-integer

in Java I'm trying to compare two different hours by converting them to milliseconds `if (20:00 > 19:30) // do anything`. In millis, it would be `if (72000000 > 70200000) // do anything`

But the smartphone doesn't do it well. I'm storing the numbers in variables `long`, as in the class Calendar, the method `myCal.getTimeInMillis()` returns a `long`, but it doesn't work.

I have tried changing the data type of the variables from `long` to `double` and it does work, so I figure out that those large numbers simply "doesn't fit" in the variable, but then, why the Java Calendar method `getTimeInMillis()` returns a long?

How does time work in Java Calendar? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Thank you for your answers and time, I'm sorry for this question because it does work to compare different hours which are stored in long variables. I have tried again and it does work (I don't know why it didn't work before). I'm making an alarm clock app for Android and I want to compare not only two hours (and minutes and seconds), but also day of the week and so on. So I'm going to mark as the solution of this question the answer of @Sufiyan Ghori because I think it can really help me, and I think I'm gonna delete this question because it has no sense.

I'm new here (and in programming in general), so sorry for this silly question.

Comment: `72000000` is not a large number, btw. MAX_INTEGER is `2147483647`, MAX_LONG is `9.10^18`

Comment: I'm afraid that to avoid anything but downvotes, you're going to have to provide a concrete example of "it doesn't work". Code please, as well as what the problem is. If there's an exception, post the stack trace and indicate which line it occurs on (since line numbers are hard to line up).

Comment: you don't ne d to compare Alarms to create alarm clock in android...you can use `AlarmManager` instead.

Comment: Actually I'm using AlarmManager, but I have problems with it. If the user sets an alarm for the next Monday for example, and today is Tuesday, the alarm "sounds" immediately. It doesn't wait until next Monday. Because of it, I want to compare Dates. Do you know another way of doing it?

Comment: There could be many issues for that behavior one of which is If you are creating `PendingIntent` of an alarm for past time it will be fired immediately...There are many questions on this topic here at SO, please search to solve your issue and post a new question if you couldn't find a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of comparing hours after converting it into milliseconds you can use `Date::before` or `Date::after` methods after setting your time into two separate `Date` objects.

```
Date date1 = new Date(); // set time for first hour.
Date date2 = new Date(); // set time for second hour.
```

You can use `Calendar` to set time for each `Date` object, like this,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,10);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,31);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,05);

date1 = cal.getTime(); //set time for first hour
```

and then use these for comparison,

```
if(date1.after(date2)){
}

if(date1.before(date2)){
}
```

and `Date::equals`,

```
if(date1.equals(date2)){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getTimeInMillis() doesn't return milliseconds passed from the start of the current day, it returns millisecons passed since 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Take a look at documentation of Calendar class: [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)